# How to use optional argumnets without - or --(dash)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, python-2.x, argparse

i want to use the optional arguments without `-` or `--`,

want to achive something like this:

```
scriptname install <other options>
scriptname uninstall <other options>
```

my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("install","INSTALL",action='store_true',help="INSTALL SOMETHING",default="")
parser.add_argument("uninstall","UNINSTALL",action='store_true',help="UNINSTALL SOMETHING",default="") 

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.install:
     install logic

if args.uninstall:
     uninstall logic
```

getting the error below

```
ValueError: invalid option string 'install': must start with a character '-'
```

Comment: Read about subcommands and subparsers in the `argparse` documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a subparser to be optional in argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570139/how-can-i-set-a-subparser-to-be-optional-in-argparse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'store_true' action does not take any arguments (`nargs=0`).  A positional with that action is always true.  And it will reject commandline strings like 'install' as unrecognized.

---

The dash is part of the definition of an `optional`.  It identifies strings that serve as flags or names, as opposed to values.  Without it you are defining a `positional`, an argument that is identified by position rather than a flag string.

So the normal `optionals` definitions would be:

```
parser.add_argument("--install",action='store_true',help="INSTALL SOMETHING")
parser.add_argument("--uninstall",action='store_true',help="UNINSTALL SOMETHING")
```

You could put those in a mutually exclusive group.  With `store_true` the default is `False`, and if the flag is provided, without any argument, the attribute is set of True.

`store_true` is allowed with positionals, but doesn't make sense.  A positional is required, so you can't get a `False` value.

You could define a positional with choices:

```
parser.add_argument('foo', choices=['install', 'uninstall'], help='...')
```

Then `args.foo` will have ones of those two string values.

The suggested use of `subparsers` is a variant on this choices positional - one where the `action` type is a special one that triggers a new parser.

Answer (score 0):

What about using "sys" module instead of "argparse"? Then answer would be

```
import sys
if sys.argv[1] == "install":
    install logic
elif sys.argv[2] == "uninstall":
    uninstall logic
else:
    exit
```

Comment: You must define what is logic and other things. Using built-in sys is much easier.